# PHP string parsing for cookbook ingredients

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have code that prints out an array that looks like this:

```
foreach ($array as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Results:

```
ingredients 1
2x egg
ingredients 2
2x carrot
cabbage
1x potato
```

The problem is the way the user types in the ingredients can vary based on user. Some users may type it as

```
1x potoato
```

or

```
1 - potato
```

or

```
1 potato
```

or even just

```
potato
```

What is a robust way to get the quantity and the ingredient type correctly when it's relatively open ended like this?

Comment: the only robust way is to build full AI

Comment: I've tried preg_split but not sure how to do it when there's no value at the front, etc.

Comment: @Lashane: What's full AI? I'm willing to look into it further.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence

Comment: @Lashane: Oh, come on. You can't be serious.

Comment: think about all possible ways user could enter such data? like `potato - 1 pc`, `potatos, half of the dozen`, `one bucket`, `small teespoon of sugar` and my preferable `several/few potatos`

Comment: @Lashane: That's fair. The one thing I do know is the user will type in a variance of the examples I provided. They won't be able to type it in that way since the database tracks all ingredient types..

Comment: so, maybe it makes sense to store quantity and ingredient in different columns in your database?

Comment: @Lashane: Oh, I currently do. This is when the user is submitting a list and I'm trying to parse it to store in the database.

Comment: Use a numeric input for quantities, and a dropdown select for the ingredients, so users have just to choose and not to type.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini: I already provide that. People want to be able to submit with a simple copy and paste though.

Comment: Better question to ask is what's the use case for this? Entering their own ingredients? If so two separate inputs one is a counter and the other is the ingredient. If you need measurement as well do a third for cups quarts tbsp etc. Or if you are having the user search an ingredien That needs a certain amount of ...

Comment: @EasyBB: I already provide functionality similar to that. Users want to be able to submit recipes with a single copy and paste.

Comment: Oh gotcha, well good luck with that lol seems simpler to do it the method we mention.

Comment: You can use regex with test on three capture groups one is_numerical then testing if it's in the array for cups quarts etc. Then finally last would have to be the ingredient. So no matter how they type it it'll come out the way you want. Ex. 1 cup chopped onions, parsley 3 tbsp. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple method for parsing inputs, it's not perfect but nothing like this will ever fully work the way you want it to.

```
$ingredients = Array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $matches = Array();
    if(!preg_match("/^.*?(\d+).*?(\S+)(\s+)?$/", $line, $matches))
        array_push($ingredients, Array(1, $line));
    else
        array_push($ingredients, Array(intval($matches[1]), $matches[2]));
}
```

[Here it is in action](http://3v4l.org/PVIL3)

---

**Addendum**

OP implemented the code like so

```
$parsedCards = Array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $temp = Array();
    if(!preg_match('/(\d+).*?\s+(.+)\s/', $line, $temp)) {
        array_push($parsedCards, Array(1, ltrim($line)));
    } else {
        array_push($parsedCards, Array(intval($temp[1]), $temp[2]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks legit. Let me go test.

Comment: Tried it out and the results look different from yours? [1," 1x potato "] the ingredient still has the quantity part left in the string?

Comment: Ah there's a space at the end of it, replace the regex from `/^(\d+).*?(\S+)$/` to `/^.*?(\d+).*?(\S+)(\s+)?$/`. [Example here](http://3v4l.org/PVIL3).

Comment: That is closer but it's removing some text. [1,"dog"] expected result is [1,"hot dog"]

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to parse ingredients with names that have more than one word in them without going overly complicated

Comment: Question, how do you make it so the number goes to $matches[1] and the string goes to $matches[2]?

Comment: In regexp parentheses (`( )`) define a 'group', so `\d+` would just match a number but it wouldn't actually store it, whether as `(\d+)` would store it as a group. `preg_match()` has a parameter that allows you to input an array and then it will fill it with the matched groups, in this case `$matches[0]` would be the entire matched string regardless of parentheses, `$matches[1]` would be the number because it is the first group in the expression, and `$matches[2]` would be the string because it is the second group in the expression.

Comment: This is what I came up with. If you update your answer I'll choose yours as the right one. I wouldn't have been able to do it without your help.
if(!preg_match('/(\d+).*?\s+(.+)\s/', $line, $temp)) {
                    array_push($parsedCards, Array(1, ltrim($line)));
                }
                else {
                    array_push($parsedCards, Array(intval($temp[1]), $temp[2]));
                }

Comment: I'll update it to the extended regexp and add your code as an addendum

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using regular expressions to search for a possible quantity and then the name of the ingredient.  This could be built [simply](http://regexr.com/3ar5l) or with more complexity that I won't attempt, but there are many possibilities with using regular expressions.

Comment: I kind of suck at  regular expressions but that is a good point. I'll add it as a tag.

Comment: Should have been just a comment this is not a SO answer.

Comment: I did technically provide an answer with my link.

Comment: Providing code and explanations are what constitutes as a just answer sorry but still should have been a comment.